# Where to put files into my Ubuntu server so I can access them publicly from a web browser?

Tags: ssh, scp, public-folders

Sorry if this is a very dumb question, but I'm totally new to server administration. I already know how to add files to a web hosting solution through FTP/SFTP, however I have no idea how I can do this with a server.

I just got access to an Ubuntu server, successfully connected to it with SSH and also sent a file there with SCP.

However, I have no idea how I can publicly access the files that I add to my server.

For example, I haved added a `test.txt` file to my server in the `/home` directory, and now I would like to be able to access it, but I'm absolutely lost about what to do now. I tried accessing `http://{my_server_ip}/home/test.txt` from my web browser, but with no chance.

What should I do here?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display you files on a webpage what you would like to do if you try to access `http://{my_server_ip}/home/test.txt` you need to have an application that serves that webpage.

One of the common applications doing this are *apache2* or *ngnix*.

Ubuntu has a tutorial how to setup apache2 to serve you an webpage: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-apache#1-overview

Comment: Thank you, I did that and it works fine.